# Prediction of future values of stock prices

Tags: r

If I want to predict the stock price of Tesla for September 2021 in R studio, what function would I have to use to predict future values using data from January to August 2021? Data can be found here: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/history?p=TSLA. Is this even possible? I noticed that most predictions are done only with the same set of data used for training, they are not forecasting for the future such as for the next 30 days. Thanks.

Comment: Please add a reproducible code example to your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately your question is out of the scope of this site -  code questions - and probably it's going to be close soon. However try to look [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/) and [here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/) to start forecasting.